# Using Auto script to auto send different emails to multiple recipients at one time

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get Gsheets to send to multiple DIFFERENT emails to multiple DIFFERENT email addresses. I have modified this several times and it keeps sending the same email to each person. Now I have it modified where it is only sending emails to up to two recipients at a time. Row A is the email address, Row B is the subject and row C is the message.

```js
function sendEmail() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
      var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
      var subject = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var message = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
    
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SX-YfVk_SfssPKvSdjGmeFYZaDPNz5UTM8GFDEmBDdg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I made a copy and could not get it to reproduce. It worked great for me, although I only tried up to three emails.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's best if you only load the data once for both performance and reliability, since it's an expensive operation and the data may change while it's executed. In this case I'd get the range of the entire emails to send and then call `getValues()` to get the values as a 2D array.

Here is how I'd do it:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')

  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  if (lastRow < 2) return; // No emails to send

  const emailsRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 3)
  const values = emailsRange.getValues()
  for (let [email, subject, body] of values) {
    //console.log(`${email} => ${subject}\n${body}`)  // For debugging purposes
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
  }
}
```

Note that the number of rows to iterate is `lastRow-1` since the first one is the row 2 (`-2`) and the last row needs to be included (`+1`).

### Refernces

- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Range.getValues() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Google Apps Script best practices | Use batch operations (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)
- [Destructuring assignment (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)